# Foreach suggestions with function Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

`let intent = [{
    id: 1,
    intentName: "Quick Reply",
    functionName: "QuickReply"},{
    id: 2,
    intentName: "Hello",
    functionName: "welcome"}]`

**how to run dialogflow look like**

`intent.forEach(element => {
    intentMap.set(element.intentName, element.functionName);
  });//forech intent`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `functionName` to real function.
You can refer to this code:

```js
var quickReply = (agent)=> {
    agent.add("some message");
}


var welcome = (agent)=> {
    agent.add("welcome message");
}


let intents = [
  {
    id: 1,
    intentName: "Quick Reply",
    functionName: quickReply
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    intentName: "Hello",
    functionName: welcome
  }];
  
let intentMap = new Map();
   intents.forEach(intent=>{
      console.log(intent);
      intentMap.set(intent.name,intent.function);
    });
   console.log(intentMap);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

`

Comment: it not work with me, i'm working with dialogflow to google home hub use api v2, but i can find document for this, all doc of Google is v1